# How to create grid list of infinitely scrollable data?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, nginfinitescroll

I am working on building a web page that will display a grid list of infinitely scrollable products.  I have implemented the following markup to achieve this :

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-gt-md="3" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-sm="1" md-gutter="12px" md-row-height="1:1">
    <div  infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-disabled="busy">
        <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="p in products">
            <md-grid-tile-header>
                <h3>{{p.id}}</h3>
            </md-grid-tile-header>
        </md-grid-tile>
    </div>
</md-grid-list>
```

(All this code forms a part of a `md-tab-body`)

The problem I am facing here is that the `function loadMore()` gets called automatically. It doesn't wait for me to scroll to the bottom of the page. How do I solve this issue? Is `loadMore()` misplaced in my HTML?

Comment: Are you using some library that implements the infiniteScroll directive?

Comment: I am using ngInfiniteScroll

Answer (score -1):

Check https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat

From material.angular.org

> md-virtual-repeat specifies an element to repeat using virtual scrolling.
>
> Virtual repeat is a limited substitute for ng-repeat that renders only
>   enough dom nodes to fill the container and recycling them as the user
>   scrolls. Arrays, but not objects are supported for iteration. Track
>   by, as alias, and (key, value) syntax are not supported.

Comment: The question relates to tile grid. I don't think Angular Material's mdVirtualRepeat yet supports tile view.